# React Meteor open graph tags

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router

How to render open graph tags from server side using meteor and react/ react-router?

I don't understand how to use react-helmet with meteor and react-router.

Thx

---

**Edit:**

I built a meteor app with react. The structure look like this:

client/main.js
client/main.html ---> where i render the app on a div id:  and got the basic html markups like head

imports/startup/client/routes.jsx ---> the routes logic with react-router

with something like :

```
const myRoutes = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
          <Redirect from='*' to='/404' />
      </Route>
    </Router>
);
```

and later:

```
ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('app'));
```

(where app is the div id on my html file)

...

server/main.js

...

(very simplified)

so... i don't understand the server part on the react-helmet doc.

"... As string output" ?
"... As React components " ?

i have to "re-render" the html file from server side? 
i mean... in the documentation, it look like the server return a var as the html markup structure...
it's not clear for me and i don't know if it's the right way in my case.

---

**Edit:**
This post helped me to resolve my problem:
https://labs.redantler.com/meteor-react-ssr-52284322c2f1#.m9i4d0pal

Comment: Can you include code from what you have attempted to do? The `react-helmet` documentation seems to be pretty straightforward on how to do this: https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet#server-usage

Comment: I edited my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client side, when you are rendering React components, you have a DOM and your DOM nodes/elements are created for each component (and their parts).

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

While not required, the purpose of server side rendering is to send the markup for the page in the HTML response. This can be useful for people who don't let JavaScript run in their browser as well as bots that are indexing your content (at least the ones that won't run your JavaScript).

Now, on the server, there is no DOM, so when you render the initial markup for your React components, you render them as a string using the `renderToString` method.

```
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server"

const markup = renderToString(<App />)
```

That markup then needs to be inserted into the HTML which you will be sending to the user.

```
const html = `
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <div id='root'>${html}</div>
      <script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>`

res.send(html);
```

Now, what `react-helmet` is doing is saying that after you have rendered your React application as a string, you call the `rewind` method to get the various `<head>` values that were rendered by the `<Helmet>` component.

```
const head = Helmet.rewind()
```

Then, you can insert the values that you need into the `html` template and they will be included in the HTML that is sent to the user. Because open graph tags are meta tags, they will be included in the `meta` property of the `head` variable.

```
const html = `
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      ${head.meta.toString()}
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id='root'>${html}</div>
      <script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>`
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, i's a bit clearer. But, i'm not sure of something... "res.send(html);"  concern an express server or something more "low level"? or is it supposed to concern meteor? i going to dig this way. Thank you.

Comment: `res.send` is from `express`.